# what topological space do I get if I shrink (via continuous deformation) the equator of a 2-sphere?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

This might be a silly question but I'm just learning homotopy groups and was trying to decide what topology I would get by shrinking the equator of a two sphere to a point?
I need only know up to homotopy with a two manifold if there's a more familiar manifold I would get. Thank you
I might also say it's the manifold you get by the connected sum of two spheres at a single point? (Not sure about that, I know spheres are just the identity when it comes to connected sums in topology)

Comment: Familliar with quotient spaces?

Comment: You should ask "what topological space do I get?" No "what topology"

Comment: @DannyuNDos I am somewhat familiar, mostly in the group context (physics guy here)

Comment: @jjagmath noted and fixed. Forgot I was talking to topologists, it's a 2-torus not a coffee cup lol

Comment: Quotient spaces and quotient groups are of different contexts. Once you get familliar with quotient spaces, look up at Seifert-van Kampen Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the [wedge sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum) $S^2 \vee S^2$ (not the connected sum) of two copies of $S^2$; in particular, it's not a manifold, since at the wedge point (the point where the equator used to be) it's not locally Euclidean.

[image]

Its homology is given by $H_0 \cong \mathbb{Z}, H_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ and all other homology vanishes (by Mayer-Vietoris), so it doesn't satisfy Poincare duality (and therefore is not homotopy equivalent to a closed manifold). Its first two homotopy groups are $\pi_1 = 0$ (by Seifert-van Kampen) and $\pi_2 \cong H_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ (by the Hurewicz theorem) but past that things get complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the well written answer! If I took a torus and identified antipodal points on its equator, would that give me the real projective plane?

Comment: @R.Rankin: I'm not sure what you mean by that. What's the equator of a torus? I can see two circles that might deserve to be called the "inner equator" and the "outer equator"; which one do you mean? In any case this is a bit beyond my ability to visualize, unfortunately.