# The topological space $R(\theta,\phi)=\cos(\theta)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider the above function embedded in $\Bbb R^3$ in spherical coordinates. The resultant surface has the appearance of a figure eight rotated around the $z$-axis.

I know it is pinched at the origin and thus more of a pseudomanifold, nevertheless, via a homotopy I should be able to classify it with a more familiar manifold. It would seem like someone walking on the inside of one lobe, would end up on the outside of the other lobe. In this manner it has a sort of "twist" in it. [image] the 2d space in question is the middle upper row figure. If you follow theta on the outsideof one lobe, you end up crossing to the inside of other. (Or so I thought)

I'm new to topology, and would appreciate help in this. Thank you.

Comment: What you've written down is a function; how are you taking it to define a topological space? Are you taking a graph of some sort in spherical coordinates?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan. Perhaps I should have specified, yes, the equation clearly describes a surface embedded in R^3 in standard spherical coordinates. It looks something like a vertically oriented figure 8 rotated around what would be the z-axis

Comment: I don't think it's clear at all; depending on what kinds of mathematics a reader is familiar with they may almost never work in spherical coordinates (e.g. someone familiar with topology but not PDEs). You specified a function without specifying its domain or codomain and without specifying how you intended to turn it into a topological space; without guessing that you were describing a graph in spherical coordinates this is very ambiguous and probably where the downvote came from.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan apologies, I have specified it now. I'm used to physics where we take so much for granted.

Comment: Of course different communities of practitioners have different conceptions of what implicit conventions can be taken for granted and don't need to be spelled out explicitly. Communication is hard! No worries.

Comment: Also the Wikipedia article on spherical coordinates says that physicists and mathematicians have opposite conventions for which angle $\theta$ is and which angle $\varphi$ is so could you spell out which convention you're using?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan. $\theta$ ranges $[0,\pi]$, $\phi$ ranges $[0,2\pi]$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  In truth, this is the spherical harmonic (as defined in Wikipedia corresponding to $l=1$ and $m=0$ I am in fact interested in finding, up to homotopy, what topological spaces the spherical harmonics correspond to. I thought it interesting that the integers for each dimensions spherical harmonics matched the types of surgery that exist. 2d 0-surgery and 2d 1-surgery in this case. I wanted to know if it was more than idle coincidence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not comfortable enough with spherical coordinates to visualize this directly but assuming you are describing a figure-eight rotated about the axis passing through the center of both circles, it's the same space as in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527707/what-topological-space-do-i-get-if-i-shrink-via-continuous-deformation-the-equ), a wedge $S^2 \vee S^2$ of two $2$-spheres, and it's not a manifold and it's not homotopy equivalent to a manifold. I don't understand what you mean about the "twist."

If you could include a 3d plot of this function that would be a million times easier; I can't get WolframAlpha to plot in spherical coordinates.

**Edit:** Thanks, it's a million times easier to just use the 3d plot. This is definitely the wedge of two spheres. I still don't quite know how to make sense of your claim about a person walking on the inside of one lobe; if we adopt the convention that walking on a surface involves not passing through it, it seems to me that a person walking on the inside of one lobe is trapped there forever. Formally, the complement of this space in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has three connected components, namely the inside of one lobe, the inside of the other, and the outside.

Similarly the bottom left is the wedge of four spheres and the bottom right is the wedge of six spheres. The top right and middle left are the wedge of two spheres and one resp. two "squashed" spheres obtained by identifying, say, the north and the south pole of a sphere. This is homotopy equivalent to a sphere with a line connecting the north and south pole, and is again not a manifold nor is it homotopy equivalent to a manifold.

Comment: Thank you. What I meant by the person. It's easier to see in 1d. If I take a circle and twist it to a figure 8, then the outward normal of 1 lobe becomes the inner facing normal of the other lobe when parallel transported. I guess I was wrong

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I would hesitate to describe this in terms of walking since again it doesn't seem to me that one ought to allow walking on a surface to involve passing through it. But yes, there are exactly two continuous unit normal vector fields, and each of them is on the outside of one lobe and the inside of the other.

Comment: Roger that, I wasn't worried about self intersection so much as I thought it might not intersect in a codimension 2 embedding (like the Klein bottle) a 4d embedding might make more sense for spherical harmonics whose values are complex I suppose

Comment: In the last example of your answer, I would've thought that homotopic to a torus. Because you can expand the line between north and south pole into a circle at each point? I must not understand homotopy quite right

Comment: @R. Rankin: that's a good question, but no, it's not homotopy equivalent to a torus. You can think of it as being obtained from a torus by identifying the inner equator down to a point, which has the effect of killing one of the generators of $H_1$. Formally, on the torus the outer equator is nontrivial in $H_1$, but in this space the outer equator is homotopic to the inner equator which has been squashed down to a point, so it's now null-homotopic.

Comment: It *is* homotopy equivalent to a sphere with a line through the middle connecting the north and south poles, and you can thicken this line up to a *solid* cylinder. But to get the torus you need to hollow out this cylinder, and that's not an operation that preserves homotopy equivalence. A point is not homotopy equivalent to a circle!